# Detecting a column with a default value using the Oracle Call Interface (OCI)

Tags: oracle, oracle-call-interface

I'm optimising a bespoke database layer in a messaging system to increase performance.

I'm using the ORACLE OCI OCIDescribeAny function to get meta-data about the columns in a database table.

How do I check the meta-data using an OCI call to see if a column has a default value set (in its schema definition).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you can't with the current API.

The [Column Attributes section of the Call Interface Programmer's Guide](http://cs.felk.cvut.cz/10gr2/appdev.102/b14250/oci06des.htm#sthref1021) has no reference to it.

The same question was also [asked on OTN](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=1552894) and the only reply was pointing out `*_TAB_COLUMNS`.

Answer (score 1):

You can find it in all_tab_columns or user_tab_columns because there you can find the column definitions.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however I'm looking for an OCI call to get the default status from the OCI data structures.

I don't want to have to do an additional select on those tables to get the value for each column.

Comment: What is so bad about this additional select?

Comment: I don't want the additional perfomance hit of doing another select on the database.

Comment: You only have to select it once. 'Cache' it in your client.